# How to handle growing number of STOMP topics with Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I am currently developing a **Spring-boot** app that uses **STOMP** over Web sockets to communicate with the frontend. In my solution, I plan, the clients to periodically subscribe to new dynamically generated **topics** (such as: */app/topic/some/object/{id}*), these topics are used for some time and then forgotten, and others come.

I was unable to find information on how Spring handles the created topics, and more specifically:

- Is there a **maximum number** or topics that can be created?
- What happens with dynamically created topics, that have no more subscribers and will never have anymore? Should I manually **remove** then, or Spring will take care of this?

I am using the simple in-memory message broker that comes with Spring-boot websockets, not a full-featured message broker like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Vasil Lazarov,
Answer to second part of your question: 
STOMP topics with no more subscribers - these topics has to be handled manually. Spring does not provide auto-configuration to address this.